# Using System Managed Identity in Azure Automation Account with PowerShell module MicrosoftTeams

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, azure-automation

**Using System Managed Identity in Azure Automation Account with PowerShell module MicrosoftTeams.**

The `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` supports login with a system managed identity with the `-Identity` switch.

What I'm not sure of is which permissions needs to be assigned to the service principal in order to use the MicrosoftTeams PowerShell module cmdlets.

I want to assign TeamsAppPermissionPolicy and TeamsAppSetupPolicy using PowerShell and with a system managed identity. (This of course works great using my personal cloud account. Using Teams Administrator role i.e not using managed identity)

The current assigned permissions are these:
[image: Permissions for SP]

Whenever executing the command `Get-Team` I'm able to list all the Teams.

When I'm executing `Grant-csTeamsAppSetupPolicy` or `Grant-csTeamsAppPermissionPolicy` I'm getting an error: `Grant-csTeamsAppPermissionPolicy : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` It is these two *legacy* commands I need to use.

I'm providing some code here if anyone wants to test this out:

**For assigning permissions to service principal:**

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "DisplayName eq 'automatebro2'" # Get Service Princiap / Automation Account


$GraphApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "AppId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'" # Microsoft Graph
$Permissions = 'Directory.Read.All', 'Group.Read.All', 'Team.ReadBasic.All', 'TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All'
foreach ($permission in $Permissions) {
    $role = $GraphApp.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $permission}
    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId `
    -PrincipalId $sp.ObjectId `
    -ResourceId $GraphApp.ObjectId `
    -Id $role.Id
}

$skypeandteamsApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "AppId eq '48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239'" # Skype and Teams
$Permissions = 'application_access', 'application_access_custom_sba_appliance'
foreach ($permission in $Permissions) {
    $role = $skypeandteamsApp.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $permission}
    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId `
    -PrincipalId $sp.ObjectId `
    -ResourceId $skypeandteamsApp.ObjectId `
    -Id $role.Id
}

$AzureADGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "AppId eq '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'" # Azure AD graph
$Permissions = 'Directory.Read.All'
foreach ($permission in $Permissions) {
    $role = $AzureADGraph.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $permission}
    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId $sp.ObjectId `
    -PrincipalId $sp.ObjectId `
    -ResourceId $AzureADGraph.ObjectId `
    -Id $role.Id
}
```

**Test code for MicrosoftTeams:**

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Identity

Grant-csTeamsAppPermissionPolicy -Identity <UPN> -PolicyName <customPolicy>
```

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#description]

As far as I know basic authentication is available in Azure Automation Account.

Any ideas for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please have a look at this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/grant-csteamsapppermissionpolicy?view=skype-ps

Comment: yes @HunaidHanfee-MSFT. But what specifically should I look at? I can't see anything there that would explain my problem.

Comment: That's the general documentation just for the reference and description about Grant-CsTeamsAppPermissionPolicy

Comment: @JoakimE - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: We are mainly responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues. 
For questions related to PowerShell Microsoft PowerShell Community forum => https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/powershell/ct-p/WindowsPowerShell

Comment: I am still looking for help on the issue @Nivedipa-MSFT

Comment: @JoakimE - We are mainly responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues. For questions related to PowerShell Microsoft PowerShell Community forum => https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/powershell/ct-p/WindowsPowerShell

Comment: @JoakimE - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved and how you have resolved the issue?

Comment: Issue still persists. Seems like it's not supported yet, right? Hope for support in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Cs cmdlets currently don't support Managed Service Identity.

[Managed Identities Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#which-operations-can-i-perform-using-managed-identities)